# How to get the names of all the models in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

i'm just wondering how can you return the names of the models you've created inside your models folder?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact the models are loaded using the autoloader, the only way you are going to be able to do it is to use something like the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) or [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get a list of the PHP files in the models directory as there is no guarantee that all or any of the models are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

same as above but a little tweak, Create a helper class to fetch all classes inside the model folder by using the directory iterator then append "Model_" at the beginning of each result to get the actual model name. This may fail given additional directories inside the model folder.